# Falied installing ATI X.Org binary driver!! (ATI Radeon HD 5400)

Tags: drivers, compiz, ati, xorg, fglrx

The open source driver worked well with the fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04, but it drains my laptop battery faster. So I installed the proprietary driver from jockey-gtk. It gave me this error message at the end of the installation:

[image]

After restarting the computer, I lost all the compositing animations. Compiz visual effects don't work. There is a black boarder around Docky.

[image]

I tried:

> sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx*

...which cleaned up the proprietary driver so I could install it again, but the same issue occurred again.

**fglrxinfo** returns this:

X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  139 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
Serial number of failed request:  13
Current serial number in output stream:  13

## Here is the [jockey.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1266814/) & the fglrx [installation log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1266868/)

Please somebody help me...! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar problems, while installing the ATI driver through Jockey.

I suggest you go with a manual installation by following this excellent answer: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/a/126513/47681)