# ubuntu switched back to ubuntu-2d in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers

This problem may have been reported earlier but I was unable to find a solution to this.
after trying to install Nvidia drivers my Ubuntu session changed to ubuntu-2d and I am unable to restore it to Ubuntu 3d. Which drivers I may need to install/remove to solve this problem?

For further reference, heres a pic of how my workspace switcher looks like when changing workspaces.

[image: Image here]

I would like it to be as it was when Ubuntu  was first installed.

Comment: Try this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/104527/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-via-the-additional-drivers-tool

Comment: Similar thing happened for ATI : http://askubuntu.com/questions/197644/falied-installing-ati-x-org-binary-driver-ati-radeon-hd-5400

Comment: You may purge/remove the driver you installed.

Comment: @Naveen which is the default driver installed? I'd like to change back to it while keeping Nvidia X server, if possible and of less hassel.

Comment: What's the output of **lspci | grep VGA** ?

Comment: Please refer to : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this question in another question of mine.

For further reference :

[How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)